# EF5 Core Update database Error Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext'

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I want a migration of my database , I was able to create the migration but the update database command does not pass

[image: Project]

DI

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
         options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("TravelCS")
         ));

  services.AddScoped<IApplicationDbContext>(provider => provider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>());
```

Interface IApplicationDbContext:

```
    DbSet<TourList> TourLists { get; set; }
DbSet<TourPackage> TourPackages { get; set; }

Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
```

AppDbContext

```
  public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext, IApplicationDbContext
  {
    private readonly IDateTime _dateTime;
    private IDbContextTransaction _currentTransaction;

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
          : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<TourList> TourLists { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TourPackage> TourPackages { get; set; }

    public ApplicationDbContext(
      DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options,
      IDateTime dateTime) : base(options)
    {
      _dateTime = dateTime;
    }
```

[image: AppDbContext Class]

[image: ErrorConsole]

Comment: Please, provide a `ApplicationDbContext` constructor

Comment: Done Bro.......

Comment: And why do you need here 2 constructors? Looks like it can't decide what constructor to use during updating the database and throws an error that it can't create an object.

Comment: You're using `DbContextOptions<>`, so it looks like you're using Entity Framework *Core*. Confusingly, although there is an EF Core v5, "Entity Framework 5" / "EF5" generally refers to the older non-Core framework.

Comment: @Serhii I removed the second constructor, but that didn't solve the problem

Comment: @Richard Deeming
Yes I modified, I use EF core 5.0.14

Comment: Maybe you need [a design-time factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) for your `DbContext`?

Comment: Do you select your project as Startup project via context menu?  Also, In Package Manager Console, set your data access layer (if any) as a default project

Comment: Thanks guys, it's solved

Answer (score 0):

[Resolved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DfA4.jpg)

Resolved by using update-database instead of dtonet ef update-database  O.o

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged. Please provide a summary of the resolution in the answer in case the link goes dead in the future.